# Install Google Play App/Services on Android Studio Emulator MacBook M1

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am using the Macbook M1 and recently installed Android Studio and an emulator from https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases. So far this is the only emulator available for the M1 MacBooks.

The emulator runs fine but it does not have Google Play Store or Services installed and I can't find how to do that. I need it to use google Maps in the app but I get an error. Below is a screenshot of the error message:

[image]